# create own extension for popup in magento

Tags: magento, popup, magento-1.9

I am novice to magento.I need to create my own extension to display the pop-up on  loading page in magento.I don't know how to do this.I also tried in google but direct extensions download options are present.But creating own there is no tutorial i found.Can any one suggest for this? Advance Thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: http://www.woolleydesign.net/2013/10/magento-add-popup-to-home-page/ follow the link, it shows how to add popup